# Firebase initialization in multi target app

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ios-targets

Is it possible to have multiple targets in an app (dynamic frameworks) and initialise firebase in one of them (FirebaseApp.configure()) but then use it in all the modules (e.g. with Firestore.firestore())

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be possible if Firebase is also linked as dynamic libraries, FirebaseCore is loaded before any other Firebase library, and there is not a need for FirebaseAnalytics which does not support being linked into a dynamic library.

More context about Firebase and dynamic/static linking at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md